# How do I determine the host from my Java applet?

Tags: java, applet

I have developed an applet that needs to read in a data file from the user.  I have the user pick the file outside the applet and upload it, I then move a copy of the file to the applet folder so I can access it with the applet with only sandbox security.  My problem arises from the fact that I run the applet on several hosts.  How can I determine the correct host this applet was downloaded from so I can connect to the proper host for the correct data file?

Comment: pass its ip or name as a parameter

Comment: I guess I can put it in the OBJECT tag.  Since applets "can make network connections to the host they came from" it seems the applet must have this value stored somewhere to compare against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [`Applet.getCodeBase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase%28%29) & [`getDocumentBase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getDocumentBase%28%29) methods.